# About the family of curves orthogonal to curves with equations $|x|^p+|y|^p=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, plane-curves

This question is a follow-on of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4855444/305862) of mine.
This answer provides a numerical solution ; the initial question was about possible closed form expressions.

Q1 : Is there a reference in the existing literature about these orthogonal curves ?

Q2 : These orthogonal curves look symmetrical with respect to second diagonal line with equation $x+y=1$. But is it the case ?

Q3 : Let us consider one of the orthogonal functions $(x(t),y(t))$. Let $z(t)$ be any or $x(t)$, $y(t)$ or $z(t)=x(t)+i y(t)$. This function verifies (by converting the first order system into a second-order ODE) :

$$z''(t)+\frac{2}{\sin(2t)}z'(t)+z(t)=0 \tag{*}$$

(with appropriate initial conditions) or the equivalent equation written under the Sturm-Liouville form :

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\tan(t) \ z'(t))+\tan(t) \ z(t)=0 \tag{**}$$

but with eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ (?). Is it possible to take advantage of these forms (*) or (**) in order to have a different approach to this issue ?

**Remark :** If the initial points $I_k$ (notations of my text) are replaced by their symmetrical points on the "Eastern" side of square $S$
(symmetry with respect to diagonal line with equation $x+y=1$) *and* if we replace instruction `yp=[Y/ta;X*ta]` by `yp=[-Y/ta;-X*ta]`, we get (numericaly speaking) the same curves.

Answer (score 1):

Hello  Jean Marie!

I think the thing is slightly asymmetric. I took one point, $(\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5} ).$  This is along the circle, so the normal to the curve passes through the origin.

The reflected point   is $(\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{5} ).$  I decided to numerically find the exponent $p$   that works. Then to check whether the normal line passes through $(1,1).$

My programmable calculator decided that $p \approx 0.563895524.$  The  gradient vector ($x^p + y^p = 1$) divided by $p$  is $(x^{p-1}, y^{p-1})$ and at $(\frac{2}{5},\frac{1}{5} )$  this came out $(1.491225834, 2.017548332).$   The second divided by the first comes out $1.352946204,$ which is not exactly $4/3.$  With my figures, the normal line passes very near to $(1,1)$  but not through it.

Probably some way to repeat this with high precision in, say, Pari-gp, which I have.

Comment: Hello Will ! A good idea to use this special point and its symmetrical point. So my second question is answered negatively !