# Are the semiballs induced by even p-norms the integrands of integral representations of trascendental numbers?

Tags: number-theory, definite-integrals, irrational-numbers

$\frac{π}{2}$ is a trascendental number, given by the integral:

$$\frac{π}{2}=\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

The integrand is also the curve of a semiball of the form:

$$||(x,y)||_2=1$$

Induced by the 2-norm $||\cdot||_2:\mathbb{R^2\rightarrow R_+}$ where $y$ has been parametrized in terms of $x$.

Similarly, we can get an integral representation of the set of real numbers $S=\{υ_1,υ_2,υ_3...\}$; $υ_\infty\notin S$, by defining:
$$υ_k=\int_{-1}^1B_k(x)dx$$
Where $B_k(x)$ is the semiball obtained by parametrizing the curve
$$B_k\equiv||(x,y)||_{2k}=1$$
Formed by the $p$-norm $||\cdot||_p:\mathbb{R^2\rightarrow R_+}$ in terms of $x$. In other words:
$$B_k(x)=\sqrt[2k]{1-x^{2k}}$$
(Evidently, in this setting, $υ_1=\frac{π}{2}$). My question is then:
Is every element of the set $S$ a trascendental number?
Any insight or information about this will be appreciated.

Comment: In general $v_k = 2 \frac{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{2 k}\right)^2}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)}$ Is it even known whether $v_2 = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2$ is transcendental?

Comment: FYI : Differential (instead of integral) issues about these p-balls in this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4853316/305862).